# Is "I heard old war drums beat." from the Eric Bogle's song "Welcome Home" grammatical?

Tags: infinitives, syntax, sequence-of-tenses

In the Eric Bogle's anti-war song "Welcome Home" (about the Vietnam War) there is a line "*I heard old war drums beat.*". Is it grammatical or is it *licentia poetica*? I think I understand the meaning, but I do not understand how it can be grammatical.

On the face of it, it appears to use this grammatical construction that does not exist in Croatian (my native language), but exists in Latin and English, called *accusative with infinitive*. However, that does not fully explain that sentence. The word *beat* is the **present active** infinitive. If we use accusative with infinitive, and the action that the infinitive describes happens at the same time as the main verb (and the drums were being beaten at the same time as he heard them), the tense of the infinitive has to match the tense of the main verb. That is called *consecutio temporum* (that does not exist in Croatian, but it exists in Latin and English). Furthermore, drums did not beat, they were being beaten, so we need to use the past **passive** infinitive. The grammatical version of that sentence would be, if I am not mistaken, "*I heard old war drums have been beaten.*"

Am I misunderstanding something about English grammar here?

Comment: The last "I heard old war drums have been beaten" doesn't say you heard the drums themselves, but heard *about* them: someone told you.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the original phrasing, but your *I heard old war drums have been beaten* is a bit "peculiar", and doesn't exactly mean the same thing. But you shouldn't waste much time looking into the "grammaticality" or idiomacy of lines from songs. They're often very unlike normal use of English. Note that your assertion ***drums did not beat, they were being beaten*** is completely mistaken - both ***the drums were beating*** and ***the drums were being beaten*** are natural in English.

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable in English to say _I heard the drums beat/the trumpet play/the car start_ etc. even though we know a person had to make them do so.

Comment: Yes it's grammatical, but only a handful of verbs can be used this way, generally verbs of perception: such as see, watch, notice, hear, listen, feel etc. More [info here](https://www.englishgrammar.org/hear-object-infinitive/#:~:text=Most%20verbs%20of%20perception%20%28e.g.%20hear%2C%20see%2C%20watch%2C,%28NOT%20I%20saw%20her%20to%20cross%20the%20road.%29)

Comment: Some examples:  I heard the child cry. She saw them run. James felt his dog shiver. I listened to my son play [piano], etc.

Comment: "The tense of the infinitive has to match the tense of the main verb" - it seems like you may be confused about the concept of *sequence* here. In *primary sequence*, the main verb is in the *present, future, present perfect, or future perfect*; in *secondary sequence*, it's in the *imperfect, perfect, or pluperfect*. The infinitive's time frame gets 'set' by that of the main verb, so then all that it needs to specify is whether the action happens *at the same time as* or *before* the main verb.  If *the same time*, use the **present infinitive**; if *before*, use the **perfect infinitive**.

Comment: So in your example, the drums' 'beating' (or 'being beaten') occurs *at the same time* as you hearing it - present infinitive is correct here.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck I'm just curious: You say "the main verb is in the . . . present perfect, or future perfect" and then "it's in the . . . perfect, or pluperfect". What do you mean by unqualified "perfect", and how does it differ from those other three?

Comment: OP: Please provide evidence for this claim: "If we use accusative with infinitive, and the action that the infinitive describes happens at the same time as the main verb (and the drums were being beaten at the same time as he heard them), the tense of the infinitive has to match the tense of the main verb." Did you read that somewhere?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Good catch, that part of the rule doesn't translate well to English!  I should have amended it to, "Primary sequence: main verb is *present, future, (present) perfect, or future perfect*; Secondary sequence: main verb is *past or past perfect/pluperfect*"

Comment: That part of the rule was meant to cover that Latin doesn't have our concept of 'aspect' from English; instead, they have an extra tense - the *imperfect* - to cover our *past continuous*, and their *perfect* tense does 'double duty' to cover both our *(present) perfect* and our *simple past*.

Comment: @FlatAssembler If you want to change the infinitive to passive without changing the time reference, you can say, "I heard old war drums **beaten**."  That may look as if it were perfect tense, but it's actually an *elided* form of the *present passive infinitive* - "I heard old war drums [to be] beaten."

Answer (score 2):

The way some verbs can be used both as transitive and and (the former, in your example of **beating** drums) has been discussed in this case:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95805/this-wine-is-drinking-nicely-does-anything-else-drink-nicely

In John Lawler's answer in said thread, this double function of the so-called **causative** verbs is analysed. You can also consult Wikipedia on them.

Comment: Rather than providing links to the information that answers the question, please [edit] your answer to provide it in the answer itself.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, John Lawler doe not provide an answer in that thread.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Hmm, you're right... I should have checked before I upvoted this :|

Comment: @MariaA. Maybe you meant to link this question instead?  John Lawler's answer about causative verbs seems to be here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/573025/verbs-that-can-be-used-as-both-passive-and-active-in-the-same-form-how-to-dete?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thank you all for the correction. And about indicating me one is not to link to other members' answers. I only discovered this forum, and joined it, ten days ago. Should have read the rules carefully before attempting contribute.